# Can I declare a dynamically adding new button globally?

Tags: vb.net

I need help in my VB.NET project. I declare a dynamic textbox which is "dim textbox as new textbox()" inside the button and it will create a new textbox when I press button1 and I also put text on the new textbox created. Now when a dynamic textbox already created. When I press button2 I want to compare the text on the label to the text in dynamic textbox created but I got an error that says, OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT.

Comment: if (Label1.Text.Equals(Textbox1.Text)){     }

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you create the textbox in the click event handler of the button. this way, you can only access it in this event handler method. In order to use it in the other event handler, you need to move the declaration to class level, e.g.:

```
Private txtBox As Textbox

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
     txtBox = New Textbox()
      ' ...
     Me.Controls.Add(txtBox)
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
     If txtBox IsNot Nothing Then
          MsgBox(txtBox.Text)
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. You have to store the reference to your textbox in a variable, e. g. in the scope of the form instance.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dynTextbox As TextBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.dynTextbox = New TextBox
        With Me.dynTextbox
            .Top = Me.Button1.Top
            .Left = Me.Button1.Right + 5
            .Text = "test"
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.dynTextbox)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Me.dynTextbox IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show(Me.Label1.Text = Me.dynTextbox.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you create multiple textboxes dynamically, you may store them in some Array or List (e. g. in a `List(Of TextBox)`) and then you'll have to find a way to reference the one you need, that depends on your specific project.